# Complex Form Nesting in Rails - How to create the desired hash / array params output

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, nested-forms, simple-form

I'm trying to figure out how to properly handle the params hash so as I dont pass params that should be nested multiple times..

Here is a simplified(removed not-needed info like labels etc) of my html.slim code (using simple_form):

```
= f.simple_fields_for :room do |r|
    - (1..4).each do |room|
      = r.input 'adults',:collection => 1..4,:input_html => {:name => "room[adults][]"}
      = r.input 'children',:collection => 0..2,:input_html => {:name => "room[children][]"}
      - (1..2).each do |child|
        = r.input 'child_age',:input_html => {:name => "children[#{child}][ages][]"}
```

ok this with inputs of 1 room, 1 adult,1 child of age 5 we get params like this :

```
"room"=>{"adults"=>["1", "1", "1", "1"], "children"=>["1", "0"]}, "children"=>{"1"=>{"ages"=>["5", ""]}, "2"=>{"ages"=>["", ""]}}
```

what I actually want to have on params is this:

```
"room"=>{"adults"=>["1", "1", "1", "1"], "children"=>["1"=>["5",""], "0"=>["",""]] }
```

anyone got any idea on how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I don't know how `simple_form` works, but here's how I would do it in with normal `rails` helpers.

```
<%= f.fields_for :rooms, (rooms_collection) do |r| %>
  ... # Any inputs you may want
  <%= r.fields_for :children, (children_collection) do |c| %>
    <%= c.text_field :child_age %>
```

This won't give you the exact input you want but it will give you something like

```
"room"=>{"adults"=>["1", "1", "1", "1"], "children"=>{"0"=>{child_age => ["5",""]}, "1"=>{child_age => ["",""]}}}
```

---

Alternatively if you don't have persisted objects this should work

```
<%= f.fields_for :rooms do |r| %>
  ... # Any inputs you may want
  (1..2).each do
  <%= r.fields_for :children do |c| %>
    <%= c.text_field :child_age %>
```