# Rails simple-form with multiple instances of the same object

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, simple-form

I am trying to create a rails form using simple form that uses nested resources.  However, I want to be able to submit multiple instances of the associated resource.  Example below will probably explain it better.

```
<div class="tab-pane active" id="reminder">
    <%= simple_form_for @collection, html: {multipart: true}, url: collection_index_path do |m| %>

        <%= render partial: "collection/tabs/reminder", locals: { :m => m } %>
    </div>
```

-inside partial

```
<% 9.times do |j|%>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="<%= j %>">
        <%= m.simple_fields_for :reminder do |p| %>
            <%= p.input :heading %>
            <%= p.input :message %>
        <% end %>           
    </div>
```

There is a tabbed pane in which the user can click through 9 tabs to set up to 9 reminders, all should be associated with a collection (collection model accepts nested attributes for reminder).  However, the way I have it setup now, the controller only gets what was set in the last reminder in the params.  Anyway ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

There must be some way to distinguish tabs before submitting to controller. And i think answer might be [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9414261/complex-form-nesting-in-rails-how-to-create-the-desired-hash-array-params-ou).
i.e. it looks like this:

```
<% 9.times do |j|%>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="<%= j %>">
        <%= m.simple_fields_for :reminders do |p| %>
           <%= p.input :heading %>
           <%= p.input :message %>
        <% end %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: hmm, this still gives me one reminder hash that only has the last inputs as parameters. "reminder"=>{"heading"=>"last set of reminders", "message"=>"9"}},

Comment: See doc about building complex forms [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#building-complex-forms). I think you should to add `accepts_nested_attributes_for :reminders`  to parent model for Reminder.